# std::getline: delimiting character vs. character count

Tags: c++, istream

The member function `istream& istream::getline(char* s, streamsize n, char delim);` enables you to extract characters from the stream until one of 3 things happens:

1. the specified delimiting character is found,
2. `n - 1` characters are read from the stream, or
3. An EOF or error occurs

Obviously, condition 3 (an error occurs) is easy to detect.  But how can the caller distinguish between conditions (1) and (2)?  How can you tell if a delimiting character was, or not?  It's possible that `n - 1` characters were read, but a delimiting character wasn't found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline

In situation 3, `setstate(eofbit)` will be executed.

In situation 2, `setstate(failbit)` will be executed.

Answer (score 1):

You can unask the question. Use `getline(std::basic_istream&, std::basic_string&, Elem delim);`. Or if you're using C++11, that's `getline(std::basic_istream&&, std::basic_string&, Elem delim);`. That is, read into a `std::string`. If you do that, you don't have to deal with array sizes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::istream::gcount()` to know the count of characters read, and compare it with `n` to figure out the answers to your questions. Also, the output buffer can be searched to figure out the delim.